# How to convert date to text Month?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I convert the date to a month spelled out?

For example.

`01/08/2015` = January

I have it code in excel `=TEXT(value, "MMMM")` but we are shifting away from Excel to SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`DATENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function.

For example:

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, DateCol) AS [Month]
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, youDateField)) as Month
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: And now you're just repeating my answer... meh.. :-/

Comment: @Amit, I did not see your msg while I was editing back and forth. Had I, I would have not pursued correcting my original answer that used datetime instead of datename. Moreover, this is a very standard answer from the manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
select datename(month,convert(varchar,yourField,106)) as month
from yourTable
```